# Select Options disappearing

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

**What's happening:**
I have a form in a modal where the user inputs data. The form is only populated with data when opening the modal, not after submission. The form's action `InsertLabelDefectRobotsT` returns a `return NoContent();` When the form is submitted the modal stays open and I clear the input values to allow new submissions.

Now, I have two dropdowns (`Célula` and `Defeito`), when changing the first one the visible options of the second one will change. My **problem** is that after submitting a set of values, **if** I change the first dropdown value and then change it back the option I submitted before disappears (this only happens if I submit the form and only the option I submitted disappears).

I have no clue why this is happening... and this is a very specific question, but if you have any leads I appreciate it.

**Modal**

[image]

**Modal.html**

```
<form id="formDefectsRobots" method="post" asp-action="InsertLabelDefectRobotsT" asp-controller="Labels" onsubmit="onSubmit(this);onSubmit2()">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label asp-for="CellId"></label>
            <select id="select1DefectsRobots" asp-for="CellId" asp-items="Model.Cells" class="custom-select">
                <option value="">--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="CellId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label asp-for="DefectName"></label>
            <select id="select2DefectsRobots" asp-for="DefectName" asp-items="Model.Defects" class="custom-select defectsSelect">
                <option value="">--</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="DefectName" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label asp-for="Quantity"></label>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm numpad defectsSelect" asp-for="Quantity" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Quantity" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label asp-for="Details"></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm defectsSelect" asp-for="Details" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Details" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left mr-2"></i>Cancelar</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="doSomething();submitDefectsRobots(this)"><i class="fas fa-play-circle mr-2"></i>Introduzir Defeito</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    //Changes second Select based on the first
    $("#select1DefectsRobots").change(function () {
        if ($(this).data('options') === undefined) {
            //Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1
            $(this).data('options', $('#select2DefectsRobots option').clone());
        }
        var id = $(this).val();
        var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
        $('#select2DefectsRobots').html(options);
    });

    //This changes the val of the select option to it's text.
    function doSomething() {
        $('#select2DefectsRobots option:selected').val($('#select2DefectsRobots option:selected').text());
    };

    //Clear some values
    function onSubmit2() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.defectsSelect').val('');
        }, 1000);
    };

</script>
```

**script.js**

```
function submitDefectsRobots(button) {

    $form = $('#formDefectsRobots');

    if ($form.valid()) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: "Inserir Defeito?",
            text: "Esta acção irá inserir um novo registo de defeito.",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar',
            confirmButtonText: 'Confirmar',
            animation: false,
            focusCancel: true
        }).then((willSubmit) => {
            if (willSubmit.value) {
                $form.submit();
                hideOverlay();
                setTimeout(function () {
                    toastr.success("Defeitos Inseridos");
                }, 1000);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**Before submission** (two "defeito" options appear on 3.9.V and one on 3.9.Y)

[image]
[image]

**After submission on 3.9.V** (Values Cleared, Still two options on 3.9.V)

[image]
[image]

**After submission** (Changed to "Célula" 3.9.Y and when changing back to 3.9.V only one "defeito" option appears now)
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: since I was changing the val of the selected option on submit, it would not work on the next time.

```
//This changes the val of the select option to it's text.
function doSomething() {
    $('#select2DefectsRobots option:selected').val($('#select2DefectsRobots option:selected').text());
};
```